# CSS selector for "adjacent" elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Need some help with CSS selectors as I am not sure how to express this in CSS, yet. How would I get the last span "Error" to show up when an `:invalid` pseudo-class appears on the `input` element (and of course be hidden when no `:invalid` is present)?  No Javascript, only CSS please.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="control-group control-field-nickname">
        <span class="span3 offset1">
            <label>{{ msgs.mid("nickname") }}</label>
        </span>
        <span class="span3 input-prepend">                              
            <i class="add-on icon-user"></i>
            <input class="form-field" type="email" id="field-nickname">
        </span>
        <span class="span1">Error!</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure if this is applicable !

Comment: @MuhammadOmar `!` is as close as CSS gets, but it isn't close enough to achieve this and browser support is (AFAIK) as good as non-existent.

Comment: @Quentin, not sure what you mean, but my '!' was conversational mark not CSS mark, i didn't mean that it can be used as an answer :)

Comment: @MuhammadOmar — You can use `!` to select ancestors of elements which match a condition: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject

Comment: @Quentin: You forgot the scare quotes around the word "can" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

CSS has no selector / combinator that expresses "contains" so you cannot say "A span adjacent to a span which contains an input that is invalid".

The proposed [subject](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) feature of Selectors Level 4 will allow you to select elements other than the last one that appears in the selector, but (AFAIK) not let you go up and then down.

Answer (score 1):

### If you can modify your HTML

With this HTML structure (`.span1` actually moved to be adjacent):

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="control-group control-field-nickname">
        <span class="span3 offset1">
            <label>{{ msgs.mid("nickname") }}</label>
        </span>
        <span class="span3 input-prepend">                              
            <i class="add-on icon-user"></i>
            <input class="form-field" type="email" id="field-ni
ckname">
            <span class="span1">Error!</span>
        </span>

    </div>
</div>
```

Then this CSS should work (for browsers that recognize the `:invalid` pseudo-class):

```
.span1 {
    display: none;
}

input:invalid + .span1 {
    display: inline-block; /* or block */
}
```

If you cannot restructure your HTML, then there is no CSS solution.